# I need a POE switch that can supply four 32w cameras + one 12w camera

Tags: switch, poe

I'm digging my way through all the brands and models trying to find a (preferably unmanaged) POE switch that will let me plug in four 32w IP cameras + one 12w IP camera.  Any recommendations?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is power draw a big concern? There's a range of older server grade switches with plenty of PoE ports, but they tend to have relatively high power draws (~60-100W.)

Answer (score 1):

Found the hikvision ds-3eo318p-e 240w switch which can do eight 30w ports, but it's expensive.  Decided just to plug injectors into the current switch.

I started with my router going to a cheap 8-port 130w poe switch (30w per port max, purchased before the cameras), with a 12w fisheye and two 32w ptz on the switch.  Added two more 32w ptz to the switch, which worked fine until about 9pm each night when apparently the temperature would drop enough to make a camera heater kick in and draw just enough additional power to keep killing a switch port and make a camera repeatedly reboot.

Decided to spend $0 adding the last two cameras by running cables from the switch to the 60w injectors that came with the ptz cameras, then from the injectors to the cameras.  The switch doesn't bother sending poe to the injectors.  Instead of one switch and one a/c cord i ended up with the switch and two injectors and 3 a/c cords total, and everything seems to work.

If injectors hadn't been included with the cameras, I probably would just have bought another 4-port poe switch and fed it off the 8-port switch like the injectors are being fed now.